# Is every category the dual of some category?

Tags: category-theory

I think every category $C$ has a dual $C^*$.
But is every category the dual of *some* category?
That is, for every category $C$ does there exist some category $B$ such that $B^* = C$?

I think the answer yes, and such a category is $C^*$:

Let $C$ be a category.
Since $C$ is a category, it has a dual category $C^*$, which, in particular, is a category.
Since $C^*$ is a category, it has a dual $C^{**}$.
Now the double dual category $C^{**}$ equals $C$, namely $C^{**} = C$. (Why?)
Therefore there exists a category $C^*$ such that $C^{**} = C$.
Therefore there exists a category $B$ such that $B^* = C$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It is correct, although "exactly equal" might not be the appropriate level of equalness in that situation, since it depends too much on the precise set theoretic implementation of $C\mapsto C^{op}$. A better way to say it is probably that $C\mapsto (C^{op})^{op}$ is 2-naturally isomorphic to the identity 2-functor